# Each page of the PDF in Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div>
//page1 of pdf
</div>

<div>
//page2 of pdf
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using asp.net application. I want to convert PDF, so that I want to place each page of the PDF in Div. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Split the PDF into page TIFFs or other images, then show those. ImageMagick can do it, as well as many other programs (my experience with .net is not big, but try googling for "pdf split asp.net")

Comment: Thanks,Amadan. I already tried converting the pdf to images. But I want to retain hyperlinks in the PDF. DO you have any other solution?